# Upper bound for $(1-1/t)^x$, where $x<t$.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

I need to find an upper bound for $\left (1-\dfrac{1}{t}\right )^x$, where $x<t$. It should be of the form $c\dfrac{x}{t}$. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, try this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: Bernoulli gives a lower bound, but I need an upper bound.

Comment: More restrictions?  $x$ could be negative?  $t$ could be ${} < 1$?

Comment: I'm surprised this question got 2 upvotes as it lacks a lot of details about $x$ and $t$ as pointed out by GEdgar. Is $t$ fixed for this and then $x$ is allowed to vary? Or is it considered as a two-variable function? The question as it stands is of poor quality in my eyes...

Comment: If $t\ge1$ and $0\lt x\lt t$ then $(1-t^{-1})^x\lt1+xt^{-1}(e-1)$ is a crude upper bound, somewhat in the form you ask for (actually, the proof relies on $x\lt t$ but since the quantity decreases in $x$, you recover the result for all $x\gt0$)